# how to turn protocol number to name with python?

Tags: python, networking

the protocol like tcp and udp is all represented by a number.

```
import socket
socket.getprotocobyname('tcp')
```

the above code will return 6.

How I can get the protocol name if I know the protocol number?

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue24809

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to say there is almost definitely a better way then this, but all the protocol names (and values) are stored as constants prefixed by `"IPPROTO_"` so you can create a lookup table by iterating over the values in the module:

```
import socket
prefix = "IPPROTO_"
table = {num:name[len(prefix):] 
          for name,num in vars(socket).items()
            if name.startswith(prefix)}

assert table[6] == 'TCP'
assert table[0x11] == 'UDP'
print(len(table)) # in python 3.10.0 this has 30 entries
from pprint import pprint
pprint(table) # if you want to see what is available to you
```

Comment: While it gives protocols up to `6` that's tcp (except 3 and 5), it is unable to give beyond that. Say 11 is for UDP for which the above script gives a key-error.

Comment: @RatDon `table[17] == 'UDP'` and according to [microsoft's protocol numbers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc959827.aspx) UDP is associated with 17.  Not sure where 11 is coming from but I frankly don't know much about this area, sorry I can't be more help to you.

Comment: sorry, My mistake, I took the hexadecimel number which is '11'. But still 132 is not available which is for SCTP. Yeah I agree. few fields are available but not all. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Python's [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getservbyport) module will do that:

```
import socket
socket.getservbyport(80)
```

Results in

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getservbyport(6)
'zip'
>>> socket.getservbyport(80)
'http'
```

As the documentation mentioned for `socket.getservbyname(servicename[, protocolname]`) and `socket.getservbyport(port[, protocolname])`. The second optional protocol name, if given, should be 'tcp' or 'udp', otherwise any protocol will match.

Comment: is socket.getservbyport(6) "tcp" ?

Comment: nope, it's 'zip', I don't think this is the right thing

Comment: @salomonderossi, are you able to use `getservbyport` in any way to associate `6` with `tcp`? The OP is asking "given 6 how can I get back 'tcp'" which you do not do in your answer.