# how to turn protocol number to name with java?

Tags: java

I need to be able to get the IP protocol name by its number and vice versa.
Something like

```
IPProtocols.get(6) // returns "TCP"
IPProtocols.get("TCP") // returns 6
```

I could build myself from IANA list, but I feel something like that should exist in java.

Comment: Just checked the whole `java.net` package and didn't find anything close, so I don't think you'll find what you want out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Andreas, two points, there is such [thing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004965/how-to-turn-protocol-number-to-name-with-python). Second, I think, I'm not the first one who needs this king of functionality.

Comment: I think you can make an enum with support to look it up via string value or numeric value

Comment: @vikingsteve, thank you. I know I can do it, but it's about 130 enum values, so I would prefer not to do it, if someone already did it. The accepted answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using (or want to use) this [IPProtocols](https://github.com/lbchen/ODL/blob/master/opendaylight/sal/api/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/controller/sal/utils/IPProtocols.java) class , the relevant static methods are provided :

```
   IPProtocols.getProtocolName(int number)
```

will give you the name from the `int` value  (this method is oveloaded to also accept `short` or `byte`).

```
   IPProtocols.getProtocolNumberInt(String name)
```

will give you the `int` value from the name (another method called `getProtocolNumberShort` will give it as a `short` value, and `getProtocolNumberByte` as a `byte` value).